# SetCookie seems to not working correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

What I'm trying to do is set `cookie` to `Response` after some `Validation` on backend.

Here is my code:

**Controller**

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
   public ActionResult Index()
   {
       var cookie = new HttpCookie("cookie-key", "true")
        {
            Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30)
        };

        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.SetCookie(cookie);
   }
}
```

But after that in `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies` there is no `cookie` with `key` `"cookie-key"`.

I've added a `<sessionState cookieless="UseCookies" />` to my `web.config` file but it's doesn't help.

**How can I make it work as it should? Am I missing something?**

**Edit:**

I've changed `SetCookie` to `Cookies.Add` but it doesn't helped.
Updated code:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
   public ActionResult Index()
   {
       var cookie = new HttpCookie("cookie-key", "true")
       {
           Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30)
       };

        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found reason why this doesn't work. It was `error` with `javascript framework reactjs`. There was `500 internal server error` but because of `ajax` `call` couldn't diagnose this.

Thanks guys for answers :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
 HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("cookie-key","true");
                cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30);
                cookie.Path = "/";
                Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
                Response.SetCookie(cookie);
```

1) Probably you need write **location(path)** 
2) Sometimes good do **Cookies.Add** *AND* **SetCookies**

Comment: You don't need `SetCookie`, nor `Path` for it to work. There is no point in adding it because it "might sometimes be good"...

Comment: Cookies.Add will add duplicate cookies while Cookies.Set overwrites existing

Answer (score 0):

SetCookie is for already existing Cookies.

You need to use **`Response.Cookies.Add(...)`**

That is all that is needed for your code to work.

Here is some code that I have in production that work 100%:

```
public ActionResult Login(string username, string password)
{
    var userService = new UserService();

    var loginResult = userService.ValidatePassword(username, password);

    if (loginResult == null) return Redirect("/");

    Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("tok", Uri.EscapeDataString(userService.CreateToken(loginResult)))
    {
        Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1)
    });

    return Redirect("/admin");
}
```

Comment: `Response.Cookies.Add(...)` doesn't work either. I thinke there is a problem with configuration.

Comment: Try removing your session configuration completely, to validate that it's working without it.

Comment: I've removed this session configuration. It doesn't helped.

Comment: Do you have any other ideas what else could cause this behaviour?

Comment: Afraid not, as I can't debug your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
using System.Net;

var response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;

foreach( Cookie cook in response.Cookies)
{
     // set your expiration here
     cook.Expires = DateTime.MinValue;
}
```